# Can I detect human vs bot visitor using this

Tags: php

Im not an expert but I observed that human visitors usually don't have a hostname connected to their ip, while bot ips have a domain name-like hostnames (like 8-8-8-8.googlebot.com).
Is this always the case and can i detect human traffic using this:

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$host=gethostbyaddr($ip);
if($ip==$host){//do something}
```

Comment: That‘s an assumption you should not make. This depends on the internet provider the visitor is using.

Comment: Are you trying to identify malicious bots or crawling/indexing bots? Most legitimate say so in their user agent

Comment: I just want to filter all bot traffic and only get human visitors, for statistic analytical purposes, i dont want to use google analytics

Comment: If I run `curl https://www.example.com` is that a bot or human?

Answer (score 1):

In general you can‘t be 100% sure, but you can use libs like this to detect a bot by it‘s user agent header:

https://github.com/matomo-org/device-detector

Comment: Should note user agent can be spoofed easily though.